# SQL Order by per different values

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have table with columns: name, category and score. And I wish to order them by score per category, but I also need them to be ordered per category like so:

1. category: A, score: 25 (highest score in A category)
2. category: B, score: 10
3. category: C, score: 30
4. category: A, score: 24
5. category: B, score: 9
6. category: C, score: 29
7. category: A, score: 23
   etc...

Is there a way to use ORDER BY to order the results like this? Or do I have to use a custom sorting cycle later on the result? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of `mysql` are you using?  Later versions support `window functions` which could work for what you are trying to achieve.  If using an earlier version, you could use `user-defined variables` to achieve the same.

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY category, score DESC`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. I have simulated the ROW_NUMBER function as a computed column (partitioning by category) and then just order the result after the new column and the category.

```
SELECT a.category, a.score, (
    SELECT count(*) from tbl b where a.score <= b.score AND a.category = b.category
) AS row_number
FROM tbl a
order by row_number, category
```

You can test it [here](http://rextester.com/MHIA59427).

Answer (score 0):

I have the idea to play with ASC and DESC

```
SELECT  name, category, score FROM table ORDER BY category , score DESC
```

Maybe this can help you (show the results of queries). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select @cat := '', @rn := 0;
select Category, Score from (
  select case when @cat = Category then @rn := @rn + 1 else @rn := 1 end rn,
         @cat := Category, 
         Category, 
         Score
  from tbl
  order by Category, Score desc
) a order by rn, Category
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/svp1HYD5nf9fUnRBh8Rr4R/0)